# JQuery UI Sorting Breaks A Element Href Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

### Example

https://jsfiddle.net/e80tL2kL/

- To start with you can click the text in the bars and they will all
  open up google in a new tab.
- Proceed to click the edit button and you will be able to drag the
  tabs around but **not** be able to click the text to open google.
- Click edit again and it **should** disable movement and enable links
  again.
- However clicking the text of a bar which has been moved does **not** open the link on the first click but clicking it a second time will.

---

For this example I'm using

```
$('a').attr('onclick', 'return true;');
```

to re-enable links.

However I have tried using:

```
$('a').attr('onclick', '');
```

---

```
$('a').attr('onclick', null);
```

---

```
$('a').attr('onclick', '').unbind('click');
```

---

```
$('a').prop('onclick',null).off('click');
```

---

All of which have the same result.

Why does this "first click doesn't work after moving" happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a bug with `jquery-ui`, but you can fix it easily. There's a `bind` that doesn't get `unbind` on `disable`. You can `unbind` it manually like this:

```
    } else if (edit == true) {
        edit = false;
        $("#sortable").sortable('disable');
        $("#sortable").unbind('click.sortable');
        $('a').attr('onclick', 'return true');

    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rh27oxph/1/